# Spring R2DBC Multi Datasource with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc

I created a service that connects to two schemas (ex. fo_pgdb, if_pgdb) My issue is when the service queries the table in the if_pgdb schema it looks as though it is querying the table in the fo_pgdb schema. I have checked and hard coded the database URLs in both class attributes (shown in code examples below) look fine.  What could be the issue?

example:
query on table in fo_pgdb schema is "select * from bid_lines where bidlinseqnumber in (123, 345) returns a result set. because ids 123 and 345 have records in the table.

query on table in if_pgdb schema is "select * from bid_lines where bidlinseqnumber in (567, 8910) returns empty result set.  But ids 567 and 8910 those records with those ids  are in the table.

test: when I use the ids 123 and 345 in the query on the table in the if_pgdb schema I get the same records that are in the table that are in the fo_pgdb table.  That should not happen.

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(entityOperationsRef = "foEntityTemplate", basePackages = "com.r2dbc.poc.repository")
public class FODatabaseConfig {

    //@Value("${spring.r2dbc.fo.connection.url}")
    private String url = "r2dbc:postgresql://username:password@database-dev-fo-css-rr-db.corp.com:1200/fo_pgdb";

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("foConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory foConnectionFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactories.get(url);
    }

    @Bean
    public R2dbcEntityOperations foEntityTemplate(@Qualifier("foConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy strategy = new DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE);
        DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.builder()
                .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .bindMarkers(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE.getBindMarkersFactory())
                .build();

        return new R2dbcEntityTemplate(databaseClient, strategy);
    }
    
}

@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(entityOperationsRef = "ifEntityTemplate")
public class IFDatabaseConfig {


    //@Value("${spring.r2dbc.if.connection.url}")
    private String url = "r2dbc:postgresql://username:password@database-blue-if-CSS-db.corp.com:1200/if_pgdb";

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("ifConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory ifConnectionFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactories.get(url);
    }

    @Bean
    public R2dbcEntityOperations ifEntityTemplate(@Qualifier("ifConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy strategy = new DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE);
        DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.builder()
                .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                .bindMarkers(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE.getBindMarkersFactory())
                .build();

        return new R2dbcEntityTemplate(databaseClient, strategy);
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CrewMemberSchedulePeriodPaymentService {

    private final FOCrewMemberBidLineRepository foCrewMemberBidlineRepository;

    private final IFCrewMemberBidLineRepository ifCrewMemberBidLineRepository;

    public Flux<FOCrewMemberBidLine> getFOBidLines(List<Long> id) {
        return foCrewMemberBidlineRepository.findAllById(id);
    }

    public Flux<IFCrewMemberBidLine> getIFBidLines(List<Long> id) {
       return ifCrewMemberBidLineRepository.findAllById(id);
    }

}

@Repository
public interface FOCrewMemberBidLineRepository extends R2dbcRepository<FOCrewMemberBidLine, Long> {

    @Override
    Flux<FOCrewMemberBidLine> findAllById(Iterable<Long> longs);
}


@Repository
public interface IFCrewMemberBidLineRepository extends R2dbcRepository<IFCrewMemberBidLine, Long> {
    @Override
    Flux<IFCrewMemberBidLine> findAllById(Iterable<Long> longs);
}

@Table(value = "BID_LINES")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class FOCrewMemberBidLine {

    @Id
    @Column(value = "bidlinseqnumber")
    private Long bidlinseqnumber;

    @Column(value = "bidlinschedperiod")
    private String bidlinschedperiod;
}

@Table(value = "BID_LINES")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class IFCrewMemberBidLine {

    @Id
    @Column(value = "bidlinseqnumber")
    private Long bidlinseqnumber;

    @Column(value = "bidlinschedperiod")
    private String bidlinschedperiod;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be you can add the connection factory invkoing the method, like this:

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("foConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory foConnectionFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactories.get("r2dbc:postgresql://username:password@database-dev-fo-css-rr-db.corp.com:1200/fo_pgdb");
  }

@Bean
@Qualifier("ifConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory ifConnectionFactory() {
    return ConnectionFactories.get("r2dbc:postgresql://username:password@database-blue-if-CSS-db.corp.com:1200/if_pgdb");
}
     
@Bean
    public R2dbcEntityOperations ifEntityTemplate() {
            DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy strategy = new DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE);
        DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.builder()
                .connectionFactory(ifConnectionFactory()) //<-- change
                .bindMarkers(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE.getBindMarkersFactory())
                .build();

        return new R2dbcEntityTemplate(databaseClient, strategy);
    }

@Bean
    public R2dbcEntityOperations foEntityTemplate() {
        DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy strategy = new DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE);
        DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.builder()
                .connectionFactory(foConnectionFactory()) //<-- change
                .bindMarkers(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE.getBindMarkersFactory())
                .build();

        return new R2dbcEntityTemplate(databaseClient, strategy);
    }
```

You can have all of your beans in the same class and each bean will be created with the connection factory that you need.

Cheers.